# Snowflake or Star for OLAP database design

Tags: database, database-design, olap, mondrian, saiku

I'm using Saiku 2.5 and I'm not sure how to model the following situation:

**Dimentions:**

- Category (~20 rows)
- SubCategory (~100 rows)
- SubSubCategory (~1200 rows)
- SubSubSubCategory (~8000 rows)
- Other1 (~100000 rows)
- Other2 (~50000 rows)
- Other3 (~500 rows)
- Other4 (~500 rows)
- Other5 (~200 rows)
- Other6 (~200 rows)
- Other7 (~100 rows)
- Other8 (~10 rows)

**Measuremnts:**

- Facts (~20000000 rows)

**Relationships**

- Fact has Other[\d]
- Fact has SubSubSubCategory
- SubSubSubCategory has SubSubCategory
- SubSubCategory has SubCategory
- SubCategory has Category

I'd like to know if it's better performance-wise, to de-normalize all categories into one table or leave it as it is. Each "category-like" table has a VARCHAR(8) and two TEXT().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to know if it's better performance-wise, to de-normalize all categories into one table or leave it as it is.

You're optimizing a data warehouse for read performance, so I'd opt for denormalizing the category tables.  You're talking roughly 8,000 rows or a page and a half in most relational databases.  You could keep this table in memory.

Seems like a star schema would work for you.  If the other dimensions have relations, then a snowflake schema would be warranted.

Comment: Absolutely.  But a bigger point is simply mondrian.  That pretty much demands star schema.   You can do snowflake but it doesn't work so well.

Answer (score 0):

Your categories should be in a single table, since 8k row joins are easy.

Other should be split in a few tables. This will allow mondrian to perform the join at high levels (low cardinality) when possible and thus perform better.

Mondrian plays well with both scenarios.